# PostgreSQL: как отфильтровать только некоторые из ключей JSON для вывода?

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
WITH all_values AS (
    SELECT s.projectid AS projectid,
           s.prompttype AS prompttype,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'prompt' AS prompt,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'description' AS description,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'topic' AS topic,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'context' AS context,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'use_case' AS use_case,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'subtitle' AS subtitle,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'txValues' AS txValues,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'flashmode' AS flashmode,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'skippable' AS skippable,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'videoMaxDuration' AS videoMaxDuration,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'defaultCameraFacing' AS defaultCameraFacing,
           s.corpuscode AS corpuscode,
           s.scriptid AS scriptid,
           s.promptnum AS promptnum,
           (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(f) 
               FROM (
                   SELECT jsonb_object_keys(attributes::jsonb) f
                   FROM source_table
                ) AS u) AS others_key
    FROM source_table AS s
    WHERE
        s.prompttype != 'input' AND (s.created > now() - interval '30 minutes' OR s.modified > now() - interval '30 minutes')
    GROUP BY s.projectid, s.prompttype, prompt, description, topic, context, use_case, subtitle, txValues, flashmode, skippable, videoMaxDuration, defaultCameraFacing, corpuscode, scriptid, promptnum
   )
SELECT * FROM all_values;
```

В колонке others_key мне нужно вывести только некоторые из ключей, которые есть в общем списке ключей данного JSON (а именно за исключением указанных в списке). Что-то не могу понять как это сделать. Пока что просто выводятся все ключи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
WITH all_values AS (
    SELECT s.projectid AS projectid,
           s.prompttype AS prompttype,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'prompt' AS prompt,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'description' AS description,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'topic' AS topic,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'context' AS context,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'use_case' AS use_case,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'subtitle' AS subtitle,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'txValues' AS txValues,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'flashmode' AS flashmode,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'skippable' AS skippable,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'videoMaxDuration' AS videoMaxDuration,
           (s.attributes::jsonb)->>'defaultCameraFacing' AS defaultCameraFacing,
           s.corpuscode AS corpuscode,
           s.scriptid AS scriptid,
           s.promptnum AS promptnum,
           (SELECT jsonb_agg(f) 
               FROM (
                   SELECT jsonb_object_keys(attributes::jsonb) f
                   FROM source_table
                ) AS u
                WHERE f in ('prompt', 'skippable')) AS others_key
    FROM source_table AS s
    WHERE
        s.prompttype != 'input' AND (s.created > now() - interval '30 minutes' OR s.modified > now() - interval '30 minutes')
    GROUP BY s.projectid, s.prompttype, prompt, description, topic, context, use_case, subtitle, txValues, flashmode, skippable, videoMaxDuration, defaultCameraFacing, corpuscode, scriptid, promptnum
   )
SELECT * FROM all_values;
```